# how to create a hidden administrator account in window 7?

Tags: windows-7, administrator

i am working on Window 7 Home Premium. Many time i share my laptop with my friends. i want to create a guest account for simple working. i wish there should be some superuser administrator account, to which i can login using command prompt and do every administrator functions from my guest account. i dont want the login screen to show my administrator account. it should be a hidden account. does window 7 by default have any hidden administrator account.

Answer (score 4):

- Create a new user and add it to the administrator group
- Open Regedit.exe and navigate to:

Local Machine:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts

Create a new key 'UserList',
under it create a REG_DWORD value with the name of your new user and a value of 0

or use Powershell:

```
New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts"
New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList"
New-ItemProperty -path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList" -name myNewUserName -value "0" -propertyType DWord
```

You may have to reboot, but the new user should not show up on the logon screen. I've never used any home editions, so I don't know how they behave.

I don't recommend to activate the disabled administrator account, there is no UAC for it.

Comment: thanks, how to login into window7 using hidden user, as it would not be displayed on login screen ? Is there any way to work in guest account as an administrator after some password authentication in CMD.

Comment: @nobita If it's not on the logon screen, how are you going to use it? You can do the same things on a normal user account if you just click 'Run as Administrator'.

Comment: @nobita as "run as another user" isn't always visible in right-click, you can use `runas /noprofile /user:YourUser YourProgram.exe` command in cmd to run anything as YourUser. Or try Sysinternals' [RunAs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc300361.aspx) for adding it to right-click menu.

Comment: In case anybody was wondering this works in Windows 10.  I haven't found any other way, so thanks a lot, Peter!

Answer (score 1):

Yes windows 7 has a hidden administrator account, but is disabled by default.

If you enable it, it will show on the welcome screen, just set a strong password on the account so no one else can use it. There may be a way to enable the account but not have it show at login, not sure how to do this, maybe some else will know.

From an [elevated command prompt](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-elevated-command-prompt/), run this command, once you log off or restart the PC it will show up.

> net user administrator /active:yes

if you need to disable it in the future run this command

> net user administrator /active:no

Comment: OP wants to know what the default password for that account would be.

Comment: So there is no way to make it hidden?

Comment: @slhck there shouldn't be one

Comment: @slhck if the hidden admin account has never been activated before there will be no password set. If there is one set it can be removed while in the user admin account.